# Docker Container: Unable to connect to SQL Server by name

Tags: sql-server, linux, docker, sqlcmd

I created two container on the same network and one of them as a Sql Server instance running. In the other container (with SQL Tools) i'm able to connect to the SQL using the IP Address, but if i swith to machine name it fails.

I already tried do ping the machine and the dns is solving the right IP, i also tried dnslookup and it's also working. Does anyone as a clue on how to fix this?

Full test scenario:

1. Created new network

   ```
   docker network create --driver=bridge specsnet
   ```
2. Run SQL Container

   ```
   docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=Password!123456' -p 1401:1433 -d --name=TestDBServer --net=specsnet --rm microsoft/mssql-server-linux:latest
   ```
3. Run New Container with SQL Tools (to test connection)

   ```
   docker run -it --net=specsnet --rm --entrypoint "bash" mcr.microsoft.com/mssql-tools:latest
   ```
4. Loaded some tools for troubleshooting (into SQL Tools container)

   ```
   apt-get update | apt-get install telnet -y | apt-get install iputils-ping -y | apt-get install dnsutils -y | apt-get install nmap -y | apt-get install nano -y
   ```
5. Test Connection with IP (Success - IP was 172.18.0.2)

   ```
   sqlcmd -S tcp:172.18.0.2,1433 -U sa -P 'Password!123456'
   ```
6. Test Connection with Name (Fails)

   ```
   sqlcmd -S tcp:TestDBServer,1433 -U sa -P 'Password!123456'
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as Bjoern suggested i created a docker compose file and after doing some test i realized the issue was not fixed.

Then i started to manipulate the file, tweaking the properties, and discovered the problem was on the SQL container name (**the container name had upper case letters**). I set the SQL container name to "testdbserver" and everything worked fine.

1. *Docker Compose File*

   ```
   version: '2'
   services:
     testdbserver:
       image: microsoft/mssql-server-linux:latest
       ports:
         ["1401:1433"]
       environment:
         SA_PASSWORD: Password!123456
         ACCEPT_EULA: Y
       networks:
         - specsnet

     sqltools:
       image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql-tools:latest
       depends_on:
         - testdbserver
       networks:
         - specsnet

   networks:
     specsnet:
       driver: bridge
       ipam:
        config:
          - subnet: 10.5.0.0/16
            gateway: 10.5.0.1
   ```
2. *Start SQL Tools Container on Bash Mode*

   ```
   docker-compose run sqltools bash
   ```
3. *Execute SQL Test Connection (**works now**)*

   ```
   sqlcmd -S tcp:testdbserver,1433 -U sa -P 'Password!123456'
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The `TestDBServer` part of your `sqlcmd` references a so-called [Server Alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/create-or-delete-a-server-alias-for-use-by-a-client?view=sql-server-2017). These server aliases are not accessible due to the way you have set up the Docker networking currently. If you [switch to Docker compose](https://forums.docker.com/t/how-can-i-contact-sql-server-running-in-a-windows-container-from-another-container/25274/4) to set up the networking for you it should work.

An alternative approach would be to `--link` the containers in question together.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when using a gateway and a microservice:

- Create network:

`docker network create mynet`

- Add containers:

```
docker network connect mynet my-gateway
docker network connect mynet my_service_8080
```

Doing so, I wasn't able to communicate between both containers when using container name. E.g. when connecting to the gateway container and doing a curl to the service:

```
curl -i http://my_service_8080:8080/management/info

HTTP/1.1 400
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 23 Feb 2021 12:51:47 GMT
Connection: close
```

After doing a lot of research on the net which led to nothing, I finally had the idea to provide an alias name:

```
docker network connect --alias gateway mynet my-gateway
docker network connect --alias myservice mynet my_service_8080
```

Now, I can successfully communicate between the containers by using alias name as host name:

```
curl -i http://myservice:8080/management/info

HTTP/1.1 200
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Type: application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 23 Feb 2021 12:54:36 GMT

{"name":"myservice-app","description":"my service","version":"20210202"}
```

EDIT:
After some more digging, I found that communication using container names doesn't work if the name (or alias) contains an underline character. So if you experience problems, check your container names.